# Fatal Error Symfony

Tags: error-handling, fatal-error, logs

Joomla 4.2.8 and PHP 8.0.28

Accessed my website today and noticed this error on the home page (along with a white);

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
> "Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ThrowableUtils" not found in
> /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/libraries/vendor/symfony/error-handler/ErrorHandler.php:563
> Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
> Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Error))
> #1 {main} thrown in /home/customer/www/mydomain.com/public_html/libraries/vendor/symfony/error-handler/ErrorHandler.php
> on line 563

No changes have been made to my site, and I haven't updated anything. It appears to be intermittent, I've checked and it's now online again but I've made no changes.

I am able to login to the admin area ok.

When I check the administrator/logs/everything.php the most recent entry is below;

> 2023-02-06T12:28:53+00:00 CRITICAL 207.46.13.160  error   Uncaught
> Throwable of type Joomla\CMS\Router\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
> thrown with message "Page not found". Stack trace: #0
> [ROOT]/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php(736):
> Joomla\CMS\Router\Router->parse(Object(Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri), true)
> #1 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php(224): Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->route()
> #2 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(294): Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->doExecute()
> #3 [ROOT]/includes/app.php(61): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
> #4 [ROOT]/index.php(32): require_once('/home/customer/...')
> #5 {main}

My webhost (siteground) have confirmed everything looks ok at their end.

I'm reluctant to upgrade anything until I understand what's going on.

Any ideas?

Comment: The question is that in `libraries/vendor/symfony/error-handler/` folder do you see the `ThrowableUtils.php` file? (before you re-install anything...). I do not see this error on Joomla 4.2.8 on PHP 8.2.

Comment: @Zollie Yes, I do see `ThrowableUtils.php`. Also, I am running PHP 8.2. Strangely, I contacted SG and they are now forcing https at their end which seems to have worked..

Comment: @jonboy if your issue is corrected please be sure to add your answer and close out the question.

Comment: @TerryCarter I still don't have a definitive answer to this so I'll keep the question open.